# the onClick dont get trigger when i use HoC

Tags: reactjs

I try to use HoC and when I
use the HoC to Wrapped the component this component  don't even triggers and when I remove the HoC this gonna trigger.
maybe you know how to fix it please I don't really see what is the problem. I tried remove the redux call and it didn't help either and then I try to rewirte the code and it's also didn't help

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ActionBar from '../ActionBar/ActionBar';
    import globalStyle from '../../../stylesheet/Global.module.css';
    import styles from './EmployeeCard.module.css';
    import { isUserAdmin } from '../../../HoC/isUserAdmin';
    
    const EmployeeCard = ({employee,isAdmin}) => {
        const ActionBarAdmins = isUserAdmin(ActionBar,{isAdmin})
        return (
            <>
                <div className={globalStyle.DataContainerLeft}>
                    <p className={styles.Name}>{employee.name}</p>
                    <p className={styles.Designation}>{employee.designation}</p>
                    <span className={styles.Location}>{employee.location}</span>
                </div>
                {
                    isAdmin && <ActionBarAdmins employee={employee} />
                }  
            </>
        )

}
export default EmployeeCard;
```

My HoC

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import * as actionTypes from '../Store/Actions';
    export function isUserAdmin(WrappedComponent, selectData) {
        const Warrper = props => {
            return (
            <WrappedComponent {...props} {...selectData}/>
        )
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            onRemoveEmployee: (id) => dispatch(actionTypes.RemoveEmployeeFetch(id))
        }

    }
    return connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Warrper);

}
```

My Component who use HoC

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './ActionBar.module.css';
import * as actionTypes from '../../../Store/Actions';
import Button from '../../Containers/Button/Button';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const ActionBar = (props) => {
    const editEmployee = (e) => {
        console.log('edit');
    }
    const removeEmployee = (e, id) => {
        console.log('remove');
        let tempObj = {};
        tempObj["id"] = id;
        if (props?.onRemoveEmployee)
            props.onRemoveEmployee(tempObj);
    }
    return (
        <div className={styles.ActionBarConatiner}>
            <Link to={{ pathname: `/edit/${props.employee.id}`, state: { employees: props.employee } }}>
                <Button className={styles.ButtonContainer} onClick={(e) => editEmployee(e)} disabled={props.isAdmin}>
                    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" >
                        <path d="M11 4H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-7"></path>
                        <path d="M18.5 2.5a2.121 2.121 0 0 1 3 3L12 15l-4 1 1-4 9.5-9.5z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </Button>
            </Link>
            <Button className={styles.ButtonContainer} onClick={(e) => removeEmployee(e, props.employee.id)} disabled={props.isAdmin}>
                <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" >
                    <polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline>
                    <path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path>
                    <line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line>
                </svg>
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ActionBar
```

Comment: what is isAdmin?

Comment: just a button that give privlige he is true for the test